# Unable to compile Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I've just installed Qt SDK 5.0.2. It has Qt Creator 2.7.0, Qt 5.0.2 (32 bit) and MingW 4.7. My OS is Windows 8 Pro.

I'm trying to compile a project which I've compiled before using Qt 4.8.0. When I try to compile the same project, I get the following output from compiler:

> 19:44:56: Running steps for project ChessEngine...
>
> 19:44:56: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin\qmake.exe"
>   "E:\Programs\Version
>   Control\Sources\ChessEngine\Source\ChessEngine.pro" -r -spec win32-g++
>   "CONFIG+=declarative_debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
>
> MAKEFILE_GENERATOR variable not set as a result of parsing :
>   ChessEngine.pro. Possibly qmake was not able to find files included
>   using "include(..)" - enable qmake debugging to investigate more.
>
> 19:44:56: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32\bin\qmake.exe"
>   exited with code 3.
>
> Error while building/deploying project ChessEngine (kit: Desktop Qt
>   5.0.2 MinGW 32bit)
>
> When executing step 'qmake'
>
> 19:44:56: Elapsed time: 00:00.

The project doesn't compile. What's wrong here?

Comment: What compiler did you use before?

Comment: mingw 4.4 i guess. it came with Qt 4.8.0.

Comment: I had this problem but I solved it using gcc on linux...

Comment: Have you done a build clean?  Sometimes I've even gone and deleted any of the generated `MakeFile` items in the folder to force Qt to build fresh.

Comment: @phyatt: Yes, it was a clean build. There was nothing except the source code and the PRO file.